# $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$; the roots of $f(x)=0$ are 1, $k$, $k+1$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $x-2$, the remainder is 20. Show that $k^2-3k-18=0$.

Tags: polynomials

This is in an IGCSE additional math question relating to factor and remainder theorem.

My attempt:

Using factor theorem we know that  $f(1)=0$,  $f(k)=0$ and $f(k+1)=0$.
Using remainder theorem we know that $f(2)=20$.

From this we can form the following equations (unless I made a careless mistake):

$$a+b+c=-1$$
$$4a+2b+c=-8$$
$$k^3+ak^2+bk+c=0$$
$$k^3+3k^2+ak^2+3k+2ak+b+1=0$$

As the last two equations are both equal to zero, we can form the equation:

$$3k^2+3k+2ak+b+1=0$$

This is as far as I was able to come, I'd hoped that I would find a trick to 'solve' the question at this point but haven't been able to come up with anything. So I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction from here (or a solution).

Thanks.

P.S. This is not a homework or assignment, I'm just self-studying a lot of the topics I'll be seeing in A level math a few months from now. (Also my first question here.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you know the roots of $f(x)$ you have

$$f(x) = (x-1)(x-k)(x-k-1).$$

So

$$f(2) = (2-1)(2-k)(2-k-1) = k^2-3k+2 = 20,$$

which is to say $k^2-3k-18 = 0.$

Comment: I can't believe the solution was this simple all along! Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I think your second equation should be
$4a+2b+c=12$ (which will be crucial to solving the problem later) and $k^3+3k^2+ak^2+3k+2ak+bk+1+a+b+c=0$ instead of $k^3+3k^2+ak^2+3k+2ak+b+1=0$.

 From Vieta’s formulas, $$-a=1+k+(k+1)=2(k+1)$$ $$b=k.1+(k+1).1+k.(k+1)=k^2+3k+1$$ $$-c=1.k.(k+1)=k^2+k.$$
Substituting these into $4a+2b+c=12$ gives the desired expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first equation was a blunder on my part but the second equation was just a mistype in the question submitted here. I also didn't know about the Vieta's formulas but I'll certainly look into them soon now that I know about them!